# TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, abstract-class, metaclass

I am trying to implement abstract classes using python's `abc` module as below

```
import abc

class AbstractBaseClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def first_method(self):
        pass

class LearnAbstractBaseClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = AbstractBaseClass

    def first_method(self):
        print "Hello"

obj = LearnAbstractBaseClass()
```

What's wrong with the above code and why am I getting the below error

```
>>> python AbstractBaseClasses.py
C:\Python27\lib\abc.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AbstractBaseClasses.py", line 41, in <module>
    class LearnAbstractBaseClass(object):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    object() takes no parameters
```

**Note:** In the above code, I am using `__metaclass__` attribute for `LearnAbstractBaseClass` for using the parent class `AbstractBaseClass` as metaclass, but when I inherit the child class `LearnAbstractBaseClass` from parent class `AbstractBaseClass`, it works fine

**Works fine**

```
class LearnAbstractBaseClass(AbstractBaseClass):
    def first_method(self):
        passs
```

**Not working**

```
class LearnAbstractBaseClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = AbstractBaseClass

    def first_method(self):
        passs
```

So what does the error mean exactly?

Comment: A _base class_ is not a _metaclass_. You can't use any regular old class as your metaclass and expect it to work. `AbstractBaseClass` isn't designed to be a metaclass, so obviously you get an error when you use it as one.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Ok I am not sure about what abc module actually does, thought abc converts it to a pure metaclass behind the scenes, ok cool will read something about abc

Comment: The `abc` module _uses_ a metaclass to do its magic, but that doesn't mean it turns your class into a functioning metaclass.